# String replacement using recursive is not working in SQL ( First part of the string is not getting replaced rest all works fine)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the below code where i'm trying to replace a string with numerical values. based on a group by function. ( In simple replacing single string multiple times based on a condition).

It works fine but the first part of the string is not getting replaced rest all works fine. I don't know where exactly this issue occurs.

Could anyone help me on this part ?

```
CREATE TABLE #MathTemp1
(
IDNUM INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1),
YEARMONTH VARCHAR(256),
OUTPUTFORMULA VARCHAR(256)
)

CREATE TABLE #MathLogicTable
(
IDNUM INTEGER,
FORMULA Varchar(256),
INPUTName varchar(160),
AttributeValue Decimal(15,3),
yearmonth varchar(160)
)

INSERT INTO #MathLogicTable ([IDNUM], [formula], [INPUTNAME], [AttributeValue], [YEARMONTH])
VALUES ('1', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 1 ', '17.000', '2013')
    ,('2', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 2','25.000' ,'2013')
    ,('3', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 3','12.000' ,'2013')
    ,('4', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 4','13.000' ,'2013')
  ,('5', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 5','11.000' ,'2013')


  ,('6', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 6','10.000' ,'2013')
     ,('7', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 7','21.000' ,'2013')
    ,('8', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 8','26.000' ,'2013')
    ,('9', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 9','23.000' ,'2013')   
  ,('10', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 10','27.000' ,'2013')
  ,('11', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 11','51.000' ,'2013')
  ,('12', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 12','46.000' ,'2013')

  ,('1', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 1 ', '17.000', '2014')
    ,('2', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 2','25.000' ,'2014')
    ,('3', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 3','12.000' ,'2014')
    ,('4', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 4','13.000' ,'2014')
  ,('5', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 5','11.000' ,'2014')


  ,('6', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 6','10.000' ,'2014')
    ,('7', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 7','21.000' ,'2014')
    ,('8', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 8','26.000' ,'2014')
    ,('9', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 9','23.000' ,'2014')   
  ,('10', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 10','27.000' ,'2014')
  ,('11', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 11','51.000' ,'2014')
  ,('12', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 12','46.000' ,'2014')




Select * from #MathLogicTable

;WITH DataSource1 AS
( 
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [YEARMONTH] ORDER BY [IDNUM]) AS [ReplacementOrderID]
      ,[YEARMONTH]
      ,[formula]
      ,[INPUTNAME] AS [ReplacementString]
      ,AttributeValue AS [ReplacementValue]
    FROM #MathLogicTable
)

,RecursiveDataSource AS
(
    SELECT [ReplacementOrderID]
      ,[YEARMONTH]
      ,REPLACE([formula], [ReplacementString], [ReplacementValue]) AS [formula]
    FROM DataSource1 
    WHERE [ReplacementOrderID] = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DS.[ReplacementOrderID]
      ,DS.[YEARMONTH]
      ,REPLACE(RDS.[formula], DS.[ReplacementString], DS.[ReplacementValue]) AS [formula]
    FROM RecursiveDataSource RDS
    INNER JOIN DataSource1 DS
    ON RDS.[ReplacementOrderID] + 1 = DS.[ReplacementOrderID]
    AND RDS.[YEARMONTH] = DS.[YEARMONTH]
)

INSERT INTO #MathTemp1
SELECT RDS.[YEARMONTH]
    ,RDS.[formula]
FROM RecursiveDataSource RDS
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT [YEARMONTH]
      ,MAX([ReplacementOrderID]) AS [ReplacementOrderID]
    FROM DataSource1 
    GROUP BY [YEARMONTH]
) DS
    ON RDS.[YEARMONTH] = DS.[YEARMONTH]
    AND RDS.[ReplacementOrderID] = DS.[ReplacementOrderID]
ORDER BY RDS.[YEARMONTH]
option (maxrecursion 0);

SELECT * FROM #MathTemp1

--DROP TABLE #MathLogicTable
--DROP TABLE #MathTemp1
```

The output I'm getting is show below

```
IDNUM  YEARMONTH        OUTPUTFORMULA
1       2013        ( (CV3: 1) + (25.000) + (12.000) + (13.000) + (11.000) + (10.000) + (21.000) + (26.000) + (23.000) + (27.000) + (51.000) + (46.000) )/1000000
2       2014        ( (CV3: 1) + (25.000) + (12.000) + (13.000) + (11.000) + (10.000) + (21.000) + (26.000) + (23.000) + (27.000) + (51.000) + (46.000) )/1000000
```

But the output required is show below. The problem is that first string is not getting replaced in the output formula.

```
 IDNUM  YEARMONTH        OUTPUTFORMULA
1       2013        ( (17.000) + (25.000) + (12.000) + (13.000) + (11.000) + (10.000) + (21.000) + (26.000) + (23.000) + (27.000) + (51.000) + (46.000) )/1000000
2       2014        ( (17.000) + (25.000) + (12.000) + (13.000) + (11.000) + (10.000) + (21.000) + (26.000) + (23.000) + (27.000) + (51.000) + (46.000) )/1000000
```

Comment: What is the output you're getting and what is the output you're expecting? EDIT: Are you aware that with the example provided you have a space in the string during your table creation for 'CV3: 1 '?

Comment: please check the modified edits above. Yes I do aware of the spaces. Its all the same for other strings too ... what difference that would make for replacement ?

Comment: The issue is the space... `('1', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 1 ', '17.000', '2013')` should be `('1', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 1', '17.000', '2013')` and same for the 2014 one... The space is after the 1.

Comment: no its not. I tried adding the spaces and still the issue occurs

Comment: You added a space where? Look, I'll post the full code with the space removed and it will work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that in your table creation, for the `InputNAME` column, you have a space in `'CV3: 1 '` when it should be `'CV3: 1'`.

```
CREATE TABLE #MathTemp1
(
IDNUM INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1),
YEARMONTH VARCHAR(256),
OUTPUTFORMULA VARCHAR(256)
)

CREATE TABLE #MathLogicTable
(
IDNUM INTEGER,
FORMULA Varchar(256),
INPUTName varchar(160),
AttributeValue Decimal(15,3),
yearmonth varchar(160)
)

INSERT INTO #MathLogicTable ([IDNUM], [formula], [INPUTNAME], [AttributeValue], [YEARMONTH])
VALUES ('1', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 1', '17.000', '2013')
    ,('2', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 2','25.000' ,'2013')
    ,('3', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 3','12.000' ,'2013')
    ,('4', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 4','13.000' ,'2013')
  ,('5', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 5','11.000' ,'2013')


  ,('6', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 6','10.000' ,'2013')
     ,('7', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 7','21.000' ,'2013')
    ,('8', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 8','26.000' ,'2013')
    ,('9', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 9','23.000' ,'2013')   
  ,('10', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 10','27.000' ,'2013')
  ,('11', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 11','51.000' ,'2013')
  ,('12', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 12','46.000' ,'2013')

  ,('1', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 1', '17.000', '2014')
    ,('2', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 2','25.000' ,'2014')
    ,('3', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 3','12.000' ,'2014')
    ,('4', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 4','13.000' ,'2014')
  ,('5', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 5','11.000' ,'2014')


  ,('6', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 6','10.000' ,'2014')
    ,('7', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 7','21.000' ,'2014')
    ,('8', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 8','26.000' ,'2014')
    ,('9', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 9','23.000' ,'2014')   
  ,('10', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 10','27.000' ,'2014')
  ,('11', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 11','51.000' ,'2014')
  ,('12', '( (CV3: 1) + (CV3: 2) + (CV3: 3) + (CV3: 4) + (CV3: 5) + (CV3: 6) + (CV3: 7) + (CV3: 8) + (CV3: 9) + (CV3: 10) + (CV3: 11) + (CV3: 12) )/1000000', 'CV3: 12','46.000' ,'2014')




Select * from #MathLogicTable

;WITH DataSource1 AS
( 
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [YEARMONTH] ORDER BY [IDNUM]) AS [ReplacementOrderID]
      ,[YEARMONTH]
      ,[formula]
      ,[INPUTNAME] AS [ReplacementString]
      ,AttributeValue AS [ReplacementValue]
    FROM #MathLogicTable
)

,RecursiveDataSource AS
(
    SELECT [ReplacementOrderID]
      ,[YEARMONTH]
      ,REPLACE([formula], [ReplacementString], [ReplacementValue]) AS [formula]
    FROM DataSource1 
    WHERE [ReplacementOrderID] = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DS.[ReplacementOrderID]
      ,DS.[YEARMONTH]
      ,REPLACE(RDS.[formula], DS.[ReplacementString], DS.[ReplacementValue]) AS [formula]
    FROM RecursiveDataSource RDS
    INNER JOIN DataSource1 DS
    ON RDS.[ReplacementOrderID] + 1 = DS.[ReplacementOrderID]
    AND RDS.[YEARMONTH] = DS.[YEARMONTH]
)

INSERT INTO #MathTemp1
SELECT RDS.[YEARMONTH]
    ,RDS.[formula]
FROM RecursiveDataSource RDS
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT [YEARMONTH]
      ,MAX([ReplacementOrderID]) AS [ReplacementOrderID]
    FROM DataSource1 
    GROUP BY [YEARMONTH]
) DS
    ON RDS.[YEARMONTH] = DS.[YEARMONTH]
    AND RDS.[ReplacementOrderID] = DS.[ReplacementOrderID]
ORDER BY RDS.[YEARMONTH]
option (maxrecursion 0);

SELECT * FROM #MathTemp1

--DROP TABLE #MathLogicTable
--DROP TABLE #MathTemp1
```

Comment: I'm sorry.. Yes you are right the issue is the space after thecv: 1 ..... Thanks for your comment...